# Sort an JSON Object Array based on alphnumeric key attribute in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, arraylist

I want to sort this JSON array based on unitId

```
var array = [
{ id: 10, unitId: 'unit17' }, 
{ id: 11, unitId: 'unit19' },
{ id: 13, unitId: 'unit27' }, 
{ id: 12, unitId: 'unit2' }, 
{ id: 13, unitId: 'unit11' },
{ id: 14, unitId: 'unit1'}
];
```

I want an output array like this

```
var array = [
{ id: 14, unitId: 'unit1' }, 
{ id: 12, unitId: 'unit2' }, 
{ id: 13, unitId: 'unit11' }, 
{ id: 10, unitId: 'unit17' },
{ id: 11, unitId: 'unit19'},
{ id: 13, unitId: 'unit27' }
];
```

Comment: No In my array it is alphanumeric not only alphabets

Comment: sort using localeCompare?

Comment: theres a typo in array of id=13 for unitId=27 the id should be 15 for unitId=27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort the given array based on the alphanumeric unitId, you can use the sort() method with a custom comparator function. Here's an example:

```
var array = [
  { id: 10, unitId: 'unit17' },
  { id: 11, unitId: 'unit19' },
  { id: 13, unitId: 'unit27' },
  { id: 12, unitId: 'unit2' },
  { id: 13, unitId: 'unit11' },
  { id: 14, unitId: 'unit1' }
];

array.sort((a, b) => {
  const unitIdA = parseInt(a.unitId.replace('unit', ''), 10);
  const unitIdB = parseInt(b.unitId.replace('unit', ''), 10);
  return unitIdA - unitIdB;
});
    
console.log(array);
```

This will output the desired sorted array:

```
[
  { id: 14, unitId: 'unit1' },
  { id: 12, unitId: 'unit2' },
  { id: 13, unitId: 'unit11' },
  { id: 10, unitId: 'unit17' },
  { id: 11, unitId: 'unit19' },
  { id: 13, unitId: 'unit27' }
]
```

The sort() function takes a custom comparator that compares two elements a and b. The unitId values are first stripped of the 'unit' string and then converted to integers using parseInt(). The difference between the unitId integers is returned to determine the sort order.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regex combination by replacing all non-digit numbers with empty string and then compare it.

```js
var array = [
{ id: 10, unitId: 'unit17' }, 
{ id: 11, unitId: 'unit19' },
{ id: 13, unitId: 'unit27' }, 
{ id: 12, unitId: 'unit2' }, 
{ id: 13, unitId: 'unit11' },
{ id: 14, unitId: 'unit1'}
];

let sorted = array.sort((a,b) => a.unitId.replace(/\D/g,'') - b.unitId.replace(/\D/g,''))

console.log(sorted)
```